# System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 3 after Mass Email completion action from Pardot

Tags: apex, trigger, pardot

I followed the suggestion from Salesforce and modified there sample code for an Apex trigger, in order to get a Campaign Member History.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000330472&type=1

In general the trigger works absolutely fine, but we are getting errors with our Pardot integration. More specifically we received errors after campaign members should be updated via mass email completion action related to a newsletter.

In the end Pardot will not sync and we will get the following error.

> HistoryTrack: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by:
> System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 3
> Trigger.HistoryTrack: line 39, column 1

A manual sync will cause no error.

Here is my code, does anybody has an idea to improve the trigger and get rid of this error?

```
Trigger HistoryTrack on CampaignMember (after insert, before update, before delete) {          
    List<CampaignMemberHistory__c> ch= new List<CampaignMemberHistory__c>(); 
    List<CampaignMember> cmOld= Trigger.old;  
    List<String> changes  = new List<String>(); 
    List<String> CampHisId  = new List<String>(); 
    integer i=0;     
    if(Trigger.isDelete){
        for(CampaignMember cm: Trigger.old ){     
            String s;                            
            s='Campaign Member id ' + cm.id + 'is Deleted from campaign id: '+ cm.campaignId + 'by user '+ userinfo.getUserName();                                        
            changes.add(s);
            CampHisId.add(cm.campaignId);
            CampaignMemberHistory__c c= new CampaignMemberHistory__c();               
            c.Name='History'+DateTime.now();  
            System.debug('CName:'+c.Name);
            c.CampaignId__c=CampHisId[i];
            System.debug('CampaignId:'+c.CampaignId__c);                              
            c.Member__c=cm.FirstName + cm.LastName;
            c.HistoryDetails__c=changes[i];
            System.debug('CHistory:'+c.HistoryDetails__c);         
            ch.add(c);                              
            i++;           
        } 
    } else {      
        for(CampaignMember cm: Trigger.new ){  
            String s;
            if((Trigger.isUpdate)){
                if(cmOld[i].status!=cm.status){    
                    s='on dated ' + DateTime.now() + ' status changed from ' + cmOld[i].status + ' to ' + cm.status + ' by user ' + userinfo.getUserName();
                    changes.add(s);
                    CampHisId.add(cm.campaignId);                                                  
                    CampaignMemberHistory__c c= new CampaignMemberHistory__c();                          
                    c.Name='History'+DateTime.now();
                    System.debug('CName:'+c.Name);
                    c.CampaignId__c=CampHisId[i];                        
                    System.debug('CampaignId:'+c.CampaignId__c);                                      
                    c.HistoryDetails__c=changes[i];
                    c.Old_Status__c=cmOld[i].status;
                    c.New_Status__c=cm.status;
                    c.Member__c=cm.FirstName + cm.LastName;
                    System.debug('CHistory:'+c.HistoryDetails__c);
                    ch.add(c);
                    i++;    
                } else if(cmOld[i].campaignId!=cm.campaignId){                        
                    s='Changed Campaign id from : '+ cmOld[i].campaignId + 'to :' + cm.campaignId + ' by user '+ userinfo.getUserName(); 
                    changes.add(s);                        
                    CampHisId.add(cm.campaignId);                                                            
                    CampaignMemberHistory__c c= new CampaignMemberHistory__c();                           
                    c.Name='History'+DateTime.now();
                    System.debug('CName:'+c.Name);              
                    c.CampaignId__c=CampHisId[i];                   
                    System.debug('CampaignId:'+c.CampaignId__c);                                          
                    c.Member__c=cm.FirstName + cm.LastName;
                    c.HistoryDetails__c=changes[i];
                    System.debug('CHistory:'+c.HistoryDetails__c);                         
                    ch.add(c);
                    i++;    
                }             
            } else if(Trigger.isInsert){                                
                s='A new Campaign Member id : ' + cm.id + ' is added to Campaign id :' + cm.campaignId +' by user '+ userinfo.getUserName();
                changes.add(s);                    
                CampHisId.add(cm.campaignId);                    
                System.debug('s>>>'+s);                                                                    
                CampaignMemberHistory__c c= new CampaignMemberHistory__c();
                c.Name='History'+DateTime.now();                   
                System.debug('CName:'+c.Name);
                c.CampaignId__c=CampHisId[i];
                System.debug('CampaignId:'+c.CampaignId__c);                                          
                c.HistoryDetails__c=changes[i];                              
                c.New_Status__c=cm.status;
                c.Member__c=cm.FirstName + cm.LastName;
                System.debug('CHistory:'+c.HistoryDetails__c);                                        
                ch.add(c);
            } 
            i++;     
        }         
    }    
    insert ch;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're incrementing `i` once at the end of the for loop, but you are also conditionally incrementing it inside the if statement. If the status or campaign changes, except for the first row, or on any insert of two or more records, you'll end up incrementing past the end of the list, and you'll get the ListException. You can, and should, optimize your code, it shouldn't be nearly this long. Here's some code to get you started. Note that you can write methods in a trigger to help make things easier to read.

```
trigger HistoryTrack on CampaignMember (after insert, before update, before delete) {
    CampaignMemberHistory__c buildHistoryEntry(String message, Id campaignId, String member) {
        return new CampaignMemberHistory__c(
            Name='History'+DateTime.now(), 
            Member__c=member, 
            CampaignId__c=campaignId, 
            HistoryDetails__c=message
        );
    }
    CampaignMemberHistory__c[] newHistories = new CampaignMemberHistory__c[0];
    for(Integer i = 0, s = Trigger.size; i < s; i++) {
        CampaignMember oldMember = Trigger.old?.get(i), newMember = Trigger.new?.get(i);
        switch on Trigger.operation {
            when AFTER_INSERT {
                newHistories.add(
                    buildHistoryEntry(
                        'A new Campaign Member id : ' + newMember.id + ' is added to Campaign id :' + newMember.campaignId +' by user '+ userinfo.getUserName(),
                        newMember.campaignId, newMember.FirstName + ' ' + newMember.LastName
                    )
                )
            }
            when BEFORE_DELETE {
                newHistories.add(
                    buildHistoryEntry(
                        'Campaign Member id ' + oldMember.id +'is Deleted from campaign id: '+ oldMember.campaignId + 'by user '+ userinfo.getUserName(),
                        oldMember.campaignId, oldMember.FirstName + ' ' + oldMember.LastName
                    )
                );
            }
            when BEFORE_UPDATE {
                if(oldMember.campaignId != newMember.campaignId) {
                    newHistories.add(
                        buildHistoryEntry(
                            'Changed Campaign id from : '+ oldMember.campaignId + 'to :' + newMember.campaignId + ' by user '+ userinfo.getUserName(),
                            newMember.campaignId, newMember.FirstName + ' ' + newMember.LastName
                        )
                    );
                }
                if(oldMember.Status != newMember.Status) {
                    newHistories.add(
                        buildHistoryEntry(
                            'on dated ' + DateTime.now() + ' status changed from ' + oldMember.status + ' to ' + newMember.status + ' by user ' + userinfo.getUserName(),
                            newMember.campaignId, newMember.FirstName + ' ' + newMember.LastName
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
    insert newHistories;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sfdcfox! Your template worked perfectly fine and I was able to adjust it for our needs. Thanks again, your input is really appreciated by non-coders like me :-D.